# In TTR Europe, can you put a station in a city that's not connected to one of your claimed routes

Tags: ticket-to-ride-europe

In Ticket To Ride: Europe, does the placement of a station have to abut a route you control.

E.g. let's say you want to place a station in order use someone else's Edinburgh - London route during end game scoring.

You have an Ticket from Amsterdam to London, but someone else has put a station on London.

Can you put a station on Edinburgh to gain access to the Edinburgh-London route even though you do not control the route into Edinburgh?

Answer (score 8):

No, you do not have to have a route of your own linking to a station you build.  From the rules [here](https://ncdn0.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/te_rules_2015_en.pdf)

> Stations may be built on any unoccupied city, even if it currently has no claimed routes into it. Two players may never build a Station in the same city.

There is no requirement to link to your own route because there is no requirement for any route to be in that city when the route is built.

The purpose of building stations is to use other players routes, so claiming Edinburgh when London has a station and the London-Edinburgh route has been claimed then it makes total sense.

Comment: Thanks. I agree, in the context of the "no claimed routes" it would follow. Just seems it would be "harder" if you did have to have a direct link.  For example, you could start the game by placing a station in Paris which has a huge number of routes, knowing that someone else likely will build a route that you can use in the future. Seems like identifying "hubs" and placing stations -- with no pre-existing routes -- might be an interesting strategy. I'm going to give that a shot, but if anyone has explored that, give a shout.

Comment: I see you new to the site,  if your happy the answer given is correct please 'accept' the answer by selecting the tick next to the answer as this will show other users it has an answer.